# Stripe: Network error [errno 92]: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

Tags: php, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-8, amazon-ecs

Laravel serves as my backend, and I use vue as my frontend. The following issue is thrown when my vue app sends a payment request to Stripe using Laravel:

**`Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 92]: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1))`** in production server.

I read through the many responses here, but I was unable to find the right remedy to this problem.

One thing is that my web application was running on EC2 before I switched to ECS Farget; while it was running smoothly on the EC2 server previously, when a payment is made using the ECS above, an error is generated.

I reached out to AWS and Stripe Support, but I haven't yet received the right answer.

Comment: Which version of stripe-php are you using? I found a similar error [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/issues/633) that was fixed by upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.113" @soma

Comment: Can you try [this suggestion](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/issues/625)? If that doesn't solve the issue, I would recommend to contact Stripe support as mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Yes I tried but then it throws another error `Missing required param: type` but used the type param while creating an payment method.